# index into javascript array with variable uses array scope variable

Tags: javascript

I've never seen this happen before, and can't find anything about this on the internet. I'm not even really sure how to ask this question.

I can't seem to reproduce this at will, but it is consistent once it starts happening.

When i try to access an element of an array with a variable, such as an iterator, the array is seeing the iterator variable as undefined, because it thinks i'm asking for a member of the array.

so for example:

```
for(var x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    if(something != somethingelse)
    {
        var element = array[x]; // exception
    }
}
```

this for example may cause an exception because x is undefined. So in firefoxes debugger, i check the value of the "x" inside [x], it is undefined. i check the value of "x" in the for loop line, it is a correct integer. So i put a watch on the x inside [x] and find that i'm watching "array.x".

I've been using javascript for years, but i haven't seen this happen before. I don't usually debug with firefox though, so is this an issue with firefox?

i guess my question is, is there anything obvious that i may be doing wrong by accessing an array using a variable?

I forgot to mention, i do have a fix, but it's not something i would like to always do when this happens. right before i access the element inside the array, i set the array member variable to the variable i'm using as an index.

for example:

```
for(var x = 0; x < width; ++x)
{
    if(something != somethingelse)
    {
        array.x = x;
        var element = array[x]; // exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `x` is exceeding the bounds of the array?

Comment: the length of array is larger than x, so thats not what is happening here

Comment: also, it shouldn't have anything to do with the length of the array because x is undefined when its used as an index into the array, but outside of it it has the correct value

Comment: Please, provide the complete example, it may be totally unrelated to arrays, maybe you declare your array globally and it gets overwritten, I've never experiences or heard of any array iteration problems. Sounds like you're instantiating array improperly or add values as properties, instead of using push().